# fscanf not saving the data to struct?

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I have an array of structs and they get saved into a file. Currently there are two lines in the file:

```
a a 1
b b 2
```

I am trying to read in the file and have the data saved to the struct:

```
typedef struct book{ 
    char number[11];//10 numbers 
    char first[21]; //20 char first/last name
    char last[21]; 
} info;

info info1[500]
into num = 0;

 pRead = fopen("phone_book.dat", "r");

 if ( pRead == NULL ){

        printf("\nFile cannot be opened\n");
}
 else{

      while ( !feof(pRead) ) {

            fscanf(pRead, "%s%s%s", info1[num].first, info1[num].last, info1[num].number);

            printf{"%s%s%s",info1[num].first, info1[num].last, info1[num].number); //this prints statement works fine

            num++;
     }

}
//if I add a print statement after all that I get windows directory and junk code.
```

This makes me think that the items are not being saved into the struct. Any help would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: Okay so it does save it fine but when I pass it to my function it gives me garbage code.

When I call it:

```
sho(num, book);
```

My show function:

```
void sho (int nume, info* info2){
     printf("\n\n\nfirst after passed= %s\n\n\n", info2[0].first); //i put 0 to see the first entry
}
```

Comment: 1) What is `into`? 2) `printf{` is a syntax error, it doesn't work fine.

Comment: can you open the file "phone_book.dat" with text editor?

Comment: Please provide the code you really use. It cannot be the code you show, as this won't compile for various reasons.

Comment: That is not the correct way to use `feof()`; you need to error check the call to `fscanf()` too.

Comment: Yeah I was trying to shorten my code to ask this question sorry.

Answer (score 3):

1. I think you meant `int num = 0;`, instead of `into`.
2. `printf{`... is a syntax error, `printf(`... instead.
3. Check the result of `fscanf`, if it isn't 3 it hasn't read all 3 strings.
4. Don't use (`f`)`scanf` to read strings, at least not without specifying the maximum length:

   ```
   fscanf(pRead, "%10s%20s%20s", ...);
   ```

   But, better yet, use `fgets` instead:

   ```
   fgets(info1[num].first, sizeof info1[num].first, pRead);
   fgets(info1[num].last, sizeof info1[num].last, pRead);
   fgets(info1[num].number, sizeof info1[num].number, pRead);
   ```

   (and check the result of `fgets`, of course)
5. Make sure `num` doesn't go higher than 499, or you'll overflow `info`:

   ```
   while(num < 500 && !feof(pRead)){.
   ```

Comment: It should be `fscanf(pRead, "%10s%20s%20s", ...`, as 1 character needs to be keep for the `0`-terminator.

Comment: @Kninnug I'll add the fscanf(pRead, "%10s%20s%20s", ...); in a bit. But why is it sidplaying garbage code and not the data saved when in my function?

Answer (score 0):

1.-For better error handling, recommend using `fgets()`,  using widths in your `sscanf()`, validating `sscanf()` results.
2.-OP usage of `feof(pRead)` is easy to misuse - suggest `fgets()`.

```
char buffer[sizeof(info)*2];   
while ((n < 500) && (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pRead) != NULL)) {
  char sentinel;  // look for extra trailing non-whitespace.
  if (sscanf(buffer, "%20s%20s%10s %c", info1[num].first, 
      info1[num].last, info1[num].number, &sentinel) != 3) {
    // Handle_Error
    printf("Error <%s>\n",buffer);
    continue;
  }
  printf("%s %s %s\n", info1[num].first, info1[num].last, info1[num].number);
  num++;
}
```

BTW: using `%s` does not work well should a space exists within a first name or within a last name.